# Natbib: How to replace the last comma in a \citet-based citation list with "and"?

Tags: citing, natbib

Natbib's `\citet` command currently has the following output when I type `\citet{maddison-cct,ridley-comparative}`:

> Maddison [8], Ridley [13]

Is there another command I did not found, or is there a way to redefine it so as to obtain the following instead?

> Maddison [8] and Ridley [13]

(and more generally, I'd like `\citet{x1,x2,...,xn}` to output `x1 [1], x2 [2], ..., xn-1 [n-1] and xn [n]`).

Comment: Have you tried playing with the `\bibpunct` command? This will only work with the case of two citations, since it sets the separator between citations in a list. So for more than 2 it will yield `x1 [1] and x2[2] and x3 [3] ... and xn [n]` which is undesireable.

Comment: No, I did not know about that, and as you said it won't really help. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Barring better solutions, there's probably a way of hacking together a way to do it using `etextools`, which has nice list processing abilities (extending that of `etoolbox`). I can't install them on the computer I am using now; maybe I'll take a look later.

Comment: (Essentially you can use `\csvloop!` to extract the list length, if it is more than 1 you can extract and delete the last element from the csvlist, process the rest using `\citet`, add the word "and", and process the remaining item using `\citet`.)

Comment: I'm sure a biblatex solution would be possible. And likely easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounded like a challenge, and I like challenges. This is what I came up with

```
% #1 {, } - #2 { and } - #3 \cmd - #4 list
\makeatletter
\newcommand\textlist[4]{%
  \let\last@item\relax
  \let\last@sep\relax
  \@for\@ii:=#4\do{%
    \ifx\last@item\relax\else
      \ifx\last@sep\relax
        \def\last@sep{#2}%
      \else#1\fi
      #3{\last@item}%
    \fi
    \let\last@item\@ii
  }%
  \ifx\last@item\relax\else
    \last@sep#3{\last@item}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\citett}{\textlist{, }{ and }{\citet}}
```

This defines a `\textlist` which basically applies a given command to a list of arguments, and using one of the two given separators as appropriate. Then you can write

```
\citett{paper1,paper2,paper3}
```

And produce something as if you had typed

```
\citet{paper1}, \citet{paper2} and \citet{paper3}
```

I encourage others to comment on possible improvements to my defined commands, and also suggest alternative definitions using other tool-boxes, TeX-flavors, etc.

Comment: This approach, when applied to instances of `\citet` with more than three arguments, unfortunately pretty much assures that the sentence being thrown at readers will be either very difficult or utterly impossible to comprehend. The `\citet`-with-multiple-arguments approach is also expressly discouraged by the user guide of the `natbib` package. If one really has to cite a multitude of pieces in support of some claim, one should use `\citep` instead of `citet`.

Answer (score 0):

When authoryear-style and author-number citation call-outs are in use, the user guide of the `natbib` package (cf. page 9, lower half) expressly discourages the use of `\citet` with multiple arguments. An exception to this stricture -- not stated explicitly in the package's user guide but pretty much self-evident from the context -- occurs if the pieces being cited all have the same author(s). However, this exception doesn't apply to the example you've provided, does it?

The stricture against using `\citet` with multiple arguments does *not* apply to `\citep`, by the way. I.e., it's perfectly OK to use `\citep` with multiple arguments.

Especially if you're citing a multitude of pieces in support of or against some argument of claim, you should give strong preference to the `\citep` variant. To wit, one should never even contemplate writing something such as

> Jones (1999), Miller (2000), Smith (2002), Strickland (2001) and Zwicki (1915) have all argued that ...

In English-language (and in many other languages too, I suppose) documents, a sentence that features a multi-part subject noun is bound to exhaust and/or distract readers unnecessarily. Do you want to risk committing this offense?

Back to your example: Writing `\citet{maddison-cct,ridley-comparative}` is simply bad and/or lazy. To assure a proper grammatical sentence structure, you should write either

```
\citet{maddison-cct} and \citet{ridley-comparative} have argued that ...
```

or choose the `\citep` approach, i.e., write something like

```
... is the main argument \citep[cf.][]{maddison-cct,ridley-comparative}.
```