# Natbib: how to replace the last comma in a citation list with “and” when using citep

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm referencing using Harvard style citations and in places I have to reference multiple citations at once. However I've been told that I have to seperate the last and second to last citations with an "and".

There is already a solution for the text mode one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4674/natbib-how-to-replace-the-last-comma-in-a-citation-list-with-and). However this doesn't work for when you want your references in brackets, as even doing manually leaves two seperate brackets, as shown below

Is there a way to force natbib to insert the "and" between the last items whilst also respecting the brackets.

[image: Showing what currently happens and what I would like to happen]

## Minimum Working Example

### report.tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{revtex4-1}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \setcitestyle{authoryear,round}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}

```
\begin{document}

    This is currently what I get \citep{Tresco10,Regan02,DuPaul97}

    \bibliography{report}
\end{document}
```

### report.bib

```
% report.bib

@Article{Tresco10,
    author = {Tresco, Katy E. and Lefler, Elizabeth K. and Power, Thomas J.},
    title = {Psychosocial Interventions to Improve the School Performance of Students with Attention-Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder},
    journal = {Mind Brain},
    year = {2010},
    volume = {1},
    number = {2},
    pages = {69 -- 74},
}

@BOOK {Regan02,
    author    = "Fintan O'Regan",
    title     = "How to Teach and Manage Children with ADHD",
    publisher = "LDA, Wisbech",
    year      = "2002"
}

@Article{DuPaul97,
    author = {DuPaul, G. J. and Eckert, T. L.},
    title = {School-based interventions for students with attention-deficiti/hyperactivity disorder: A meta-analysis},
    journal = {School Psychology Review},
    year = {1997},
    volume = {26},
    pages = {5 -- 27},
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you do not use "and" with `\citep`. This is ok for `\citet`, as `\citet` is used in-text, as in `This has been handled by \citet{Doe:2001,Johnson:2002}.` to read as `This has been handled by Doe and Johnson.`. But `\citep` should be used as if it were footnotes, as in `This has already been handled \citep{Doe:2001,Johnson:2002}.` to read as `This has already been handled¹².`—in this case, an "and" would be awkward.

Comment: That would be true if you were using a numerical referencing style, however using the author year style this doesn't quite work. I was using it in the following format `While there has not been a similarly large scale study done on secondary age pupils, there have been  two smaller scale  studies \citep{Jenkins06,Levacic06} which found ...`. In this case surely it should read `(Jenkins, 2006 and Levacic 2006)`.